# Favicon/ icon not reflect in google search result

Tags: seo, meta, favicon

In google search result my website result showing but cant see logo or favicon in left hand side.

My html code inside head tag

```
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="24x24" href="favicon-24x24.ico">
        <link rel=icon type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.ico">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.ico">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="48x48" href="favicon-48x48.ico">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="64x64" href="favicon-64x64.ico">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="favicon-96x96.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="apple-icon-57x57.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="apple-icon-60x60.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="apple-icon-72x72.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="apple-icon-76x76.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="apple-icon-114x114.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="apple-icon-120x120.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="apple-icon-144x144.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="apple-icon-152x152.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="apple-icon-180x180.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="android-icon-192x192.png">
        <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#3593CF">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="ms-icon-144x144.png">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#3593CF">
```

Refer screenshot image.

[image: google search result]

Comment: What did you try to include the logo icon? Please post the code, which might have an unexpected error.

Comment: @Praveenkumar Question edited.

Answer (score 2):

This can be due to on-site and off-site issues.

**On-site**

Your code looks correct. If your favicon shows up in browser tabs, you can be confident it works and Google is able to crawl it. To check this, you can use the Google favicon snatcher. Visit https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.example.com (... replace www.example.com by your domain): you should see your favicon.

**Off-site**

Even after Google crawled your favicon, it still takes some time for it to appear in result pages. From my observations, the delay depends on the popularity of the site and can vary from a few days to a few weeks.

Also make sure your favicon is appropriate. For example, make sure it is not too similar to the favicon of one of your competitors.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the guidelines specified by google.

**Guidelines**

You must follow these guidelines to be eligible for a favicon next to your search results. Note that a favicon isn't guaranteed in search results even if all guidelines are met.

- Both the favicon file and the home page must be crawlable by Google (that is, they cannot be blocked to Google).
- Your favicon should be a visual representation of your website's brand, in order to help users quickly identify your site when they scan through search results.
- Your favicon should be a multiple of 48px square, for example: 48x48px, 96x96px, 144x144px and so on. SVG files, of course, do not have a specific size. Any valid favicon format is supported. Google will rescale your image to 16x16px for use in search results, so make sure that it looks good at that resolution. Note: do not provide a 16x16px favicon.
- The favicon URL should be stable (don’t change the URL frequently).
- Google will not show any favicon that it deems inappropriate, including pornography or hate symbols (for example, swastikas). If this type of imagery is discovered within a favicon, Google will replace it with a default icon.

Google will look for and update your favicon whenever it crawls your home page. If you make changes to your favicon and want to inform Google about the changes, you can request indexing of your site's homepage. Updates can take a few days or longer to appear in search results.

It might be possible that the icon has not yet been crawled by google search indexing.